# PHP's preg_replace where the replacement is an arbitrary function of the match

Tags: php, regex, debugging

Suppose I want to replace occurrences of "foo" with "oof":

```
$s = "abc foo bar";
echo preg_replace('/(foo)/', strrev("$1"), $s);
```

Instead of "`abc oof bar`" I get "`abc 1$ bar`".
In other words, it's passing the literal string "$1" to the strrev() function, instead of the regex match, "foo".

What's the best way to fix this problem in the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `/e` flag.

```
echo preg_replace('/(foo)/e', 'strrev("\\1")', $s);
```

A safer alternative is to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
function revMatch ($matches) {
  return strrev($matches[1]);
}
...

echo preg_replace_callback('/(foo)/', "revMatch", $s);
```